# len() of unsized object - cvxpy - correlation maximization

Tags: python, convex-optimization, cvxpy

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
from cvxpy import Variable, Problem, Maximize

X = np.random.rand(1000, 4)
Y = np.random.rand(1000, 4)
weights = Variable(4,)
constraints = []

def get_correlation(a):
    return pearsonr(X * a, Y *a)

obj = Maximize(get_correlation(weights))
problem = Problem(obj, constraints)
problem.solve()
```

I'm trying to use cvxpy to find the value of a vector weights, to perform a linear transformation of two matrices. The objective function is the maximization of the pearson correlation between the two transformed matrices.

I don't understand why I'm getting the following error.

```
      4 def get_correlation(a):
----> 5     return pearsonr(X * a, Y *a)
      6 
      7 obj = Maximize(get_correlation(weights))

~/Python/global/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in pearsonr(x, y)
   3030     x = np.asarray(x)
   3031     y = np.asarray(y)
-> 3032     n = len(x)
   3033     mx = x.mean()
   3034     my = y.mean()

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: Right, and your question is.... ?

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting `len() of unsized object' when solving the program

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because `pearsonr` expects to be passed two array like inputs `x` and `y`.

You created arrays `X` and `Y` in your code, yes. But if you check the type of `X * weights` (which is what you're actually passing to `pearsonr`) you'll see it has type `cvxpy.atoms.affine.binary_operators.MulExpression`, which does not have a length attribute, and so `len(X * weights)` throws an error.

Comment: I see. Is there some alternative way of formulating this problem with cvxpy that won't have this issue ?